# Data structure for extensive hierarchies

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, graph, hierarchical-data

Hey I am currently on a project where I need to find a match for a combination of two elements efficiently. The elements have the following properties:

- name
- parent element
- group

A group can have a parent group as well.

A match can happen with the following combinations (ordered by priority):

- element - element
- element - parent element
- parent element - parent element
- element - category
- parent element - category
- element - parent element category
- category - category
- parent element category - parent element
- category - parent element category
- parent element category - parent element category

Currently I implemented this using a MySQL database. But in the worst case scenario, where there is no match at all, it'll run a lot of queries and therefore is slow.

I was wondering if there is a better data structure to store these kind of hierarchies? I took a look into graphs, but I am not sure if this fits for this scenario.